# Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (463): y

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a scatter plot between 2 variables, 'score' and 'avg_bty'.

I created avg_bty and I'm not sure what it means when it says "must be same length as the data" because the 2 variables have the same amount of readings.

creating variable:

```
evals %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(avg_bty = (bty_f1lower+ bty_f1upper+bty_f2upper+bty_m1lower+bty_m1upper+bty_m2upper)/6)
```

scatterplot:

```
  ggplot(data = evals, mapping = aes(score, avg_bty))+
  geom_point()
```

I keep getting Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (463): y.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Is `score` a column in `evals`?

Comment: In addition to MrFlick's comment, there shouldn't be a need for `rowwise()` here. Addition in R is vectorised.

Comment: ...though you may be interested in the `rowMeans` function.